# One-To-One relationship with two models on one side

Tags: django, django-models

I have three relations `User`, `Film` and `Rating`.

For now, I have done my model `Rating` like so:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    film = models.ForeignKey('Film', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

However here, a user can have several ratings for the same film and I would like that a user can only rate a film one time. So I added this after the previous code:

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = ('user', 'film')
```

Is there a better way to enforce the unicity mentioned above?

I feel like this is just a lazy way of enforcing something that could have been done using relationships.

Comment: you want one user have only one rating per film?

Comment: Yes, a user can rate as many films as he wants but only one time per film. I don't want two rows in my table Rating containing the same couple (user, film).

Answer (score 0):

No this seems like [this is the way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together) to do it.

> It’s used in the Django admin and is enforced at the database level
>   (i.e., the appropriate UNIQUE statements are included in the CREATE
>   TABLE statement).

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

However, you should use the proper nested-tuple syntax i.e.

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = ((user, film), )
```

as opposed to:

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = ('user', 'film')
```

See [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together).